# React - Babel Polyfill doesn't prevent exception on Set or Weakmap for some reason, but does fill Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am trying to provide some sort of cross compatibility with IE 10. I have used the Babel Polyfill to get past a Promise exception for IE 11, but for IE 10 I am getting exceptions for Set and Weakmap which babel polyfill should correct as it was my understanding that these were included as well.

This was my first React/React-static project, so flying by the seat of my pants to be honest so hope someone can help/explain things in a simple clear fashion.

FYI: Set is undefined in the main.js file produced by react-static build. And Weakmap is found in the hot-reloader module which is only a problem in dev mode.

**My App.js file:**

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import React from "react";
import { Router, Link } from "react-static";
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader";
import Routes from "react-static-routes";

import "./sass/app.scss";
import "./sass/_base.scss";
import "./sass/_layout.scss";
import "./sass/_utilities.scss";
import "./sass/main.scss";

import "./sass/_components.scss";

const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Routes />
        </div>
    </Router>
);

export default hot(module)(App);
```

**My static.config.js file:**

```
import ExtractTextPlugin from "extract-text-webpack-plugin";

export default {
    getSiteData: () => ({
        title: "React Static"
    }),
    getRoutes: async () => {
        // const { data: posts } = await axios.get(
        //  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
        // );
        return [
            {
                path: "/",
                component: "src/containers/Home"
            },
            {
                path: "/about",
                component: "src/containers/About"
            },
            {
                path: "/services",
                component: "src/containers/Services"
            },
            {
                path: "/cases",
                component: "src/containers/Cases"
            },
            {
                path: "/process",
                component: "src/containers/Process"
            },
            {
                path: "/contact",
                component: "src/containers/Contact"
            },
            {
                path: "/contactsent",
                component: "src/containers/Contactsent"
            },
            {
                is404: true,
                component: "src/containers/404"
            }
        ];
    },
    webpack: (config, { defaultLoaders, stage }) => {
        let loaders = [];

        if (stage === "dev") {
            loaders = [
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: "css-loader" },
                { loader: "sass-loader" }
            ];
        } else {
            loaders = [
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        minimize: stage === "prod",
                        sourceMap: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: { includePaths: ["src/", "src/sass/"] }
                }
            ];

            // Don't extract css to file during node build process
            if (stage !== "node") {
                loaders = ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: {
                        loader: "style-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: false,
                            hmr: false
                        }
                    },
                    use: loaders
                });
            }
        }

        config.module.rules = [
            {
                oneOf: [
                    {
                        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                        use: loaders
                    },
                    defaultLoaders.cssLoader,
                    defaultLoaders.jsLoader,
                    defaultLoaders.fileLoader
                ]
            }
        ];
        return config;
    }
};
```

**My package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "react-static-example-basic",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-static start",
    "stage": "react-static build --staging",
    "build": "react-static build",
    "serve": "serve dist -p 3000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "core-js": "^3.0.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "promise-polyfill": "8.1.0",
    "raf": "^3.4.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.5",
    "react-static": "^5.9.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint-config-react-tools": "1.x.x",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "serve": "^6.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding it to your webpack config? Where in your app are Set and Weakmap implemented?

Comment: I respect your ambition, but unless you have a very very good reason I'd skip it. Adding IE 10 compatibility is going to be... difficult. Even though React itself goes back to IE 9, you're going to have to dig deep on every single dependency as many libraries have stopped supporting IE < 11.

Comment: Hi Jared, it's just a real shame, because I have developed a site for australian company and they still have quite high uptake of IE10.

Comment: Where's your babel config in webpack?

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth trying to separately instal [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) include such modules in the assembly:

```
npm i --save core-js
```

```
import "core-js/es/set";
import "core-js/es/weak-map";
```

If that doesn't help try use [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io):

Add yor html it:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=WeakMap%2CWeakSet%2CSet"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with react-static as such, but from what I experienced with my projects with react and webpack:

- the babel polyfill needs to go into the html page as a first script tag, and could not be packaged as part of webpack (I do not recall the exact reasons)
- On projects not involving babel I had success convincing IE10 to play ball using: https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim